# language & platform agnostic Visual Web App Designer?

Tags: ajax, web-applications

Ok i'll try to put this very simple: suppose I'd like a web page with a simple text input box which reads user input, then some server application processes it and then it is outputed to the same page in a text area under the text input box (without refreshing whole page).

What's the |easiest| way/approach/paradigm to this ?

Is there a rad tool or a visual design tool for web ui interfaces which is "ajax-aware" ?

What is the standard one? or the most complete or most used?

I feel like there is a Tool everyone's using that i'm not aware of.

Of course this tool must not force me to use a pre-determined web server or language for server side programming.

Any ideas ?

Comment: "Of course this tool must not force me to use a pre-determined web server or language for server side programming. " I think this is impossible - well, OK, it could output a choice of two languages, but that would be a lot of effort for little gain, and it would still force you to use one of those languages for any customisation outside the scope of the tool.

Answer (score 2):

Well, have you heard about DreamWeaver ? It includes a JavaScript extension (it's name is Spyre or something like that) which I think implements AJAX widgets. Also, not server-side scripting-language agnostic, but I thought I'd mention WaveMaker (in-browser RAD visual IDE):

*[WaveMaker](https://www.wavemaker.com) (formerly known as ActiveGrid) is an open source software development platform that automates much of the process for creating Java web and cloud applications. WaveMaker provides a visual rapid application development platform and is available as a free open source software download. WaveMaker was acquired by VMware, Inc in March 2011.*

WaveMaker allows web developers to create Ajax applications. The WaveMaker framework itself integrates Spring, ACEGI, Dojo Toolkit 1.0, authentication, LDAP, ActiveDirectory and POJOs and their products include Visual Ajax Studio for RIAs development and WaveMaker Rapid Deployment Server for Java application.